# How to set Celery with TTL so it purges old messages from a queue?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am using Celery, Django and RabbitMQ. I am looking for a way to purge old messages out of the celery queue in RabbitMQ automatically. So whenever the queue gets created by default it should purge all messages older then x seconds.

These are variables I set in my settings.py.

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'celery'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'celery'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery'
CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_TTL= 30
```

I also tried this, but it lead to the point that no message got send to RabbitMQ at all.

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (                                                                                                                                                                 
Queue('celery', routing_key='celery', queue_arguments={'x-message-ttl': 30}),                                                                                                 
Queue('default', routing_key='default', queue_arguments={'x-message-ttl': 30}),                                                                                               
)
```

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 7):

x-message-ttl is in **milliseconds** - **NOT SECONDS**.

You want to put something like this in your celery config file:

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

CELERY_QUEUES = [
                     Queue(
                         'celery',
                         Exchange('celery'),
                         routing_key = 'celery',
                         queue_arguments = {
                                                'x-message-ttl': 30000
                                           }
                     )
                ]
```

Comment: so, celery's default queue configurations are useless then? im not sure what purpose they serve

Answer (score 2):

The option CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_TTL= 30 is only for Events and not for Tasks as the name states. Celery will keep a message for a task as long as necessary, which makes sense.

In my case I used RabbitMQ Federation which doubled the queue. Switching to Shovel solved the issue for me.